# Install python 3.7 on wine 5.0

Tags: software-installation, python, wine

I am trying to install Python 3.7.8 on Wine 5.0 to be able to cross-compile my python projects for Windows. I have not installed wine32 yet, but I don't mind doing so. I have downloaded the python installer executable (python-3.7.8-amd64.exe) and I have tried doing `wine python-3.7.8-amd64.exe` but I get this error:

```
0010:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0010:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0010:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0010:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0010:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
```

Then I tried downloading the embedded zip file, and extracted it on `~/.wine/drive_c/python37/` Then I executed it from the terminal like this: `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/python37/python.exe` Which gave me this error:

```
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
```

How can I fix this issue? Is there any other way for me to install python 3.7 on wine?

Comment: I wonder if you'd have better luck with `winetricks` as described in the [top answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330141/install-python-in-wine).

Comment: @BrianZ I tried winetricks but I can only install python26 or pyton27, and I need python37

Comment: I see. Python 3.7.4 with Wine 4.14 is rated Platinum [on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=38187). Would that work for you or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not solved the issue itself, but I have found a workaround I think, I just used sudo and it worked perfectly. The only disadvantage is that I need root constantly to use python in wine, but at least it works

Comment: This worked with me too with pyton 3.8.0 but not with 3.9.0. Would appreciate if someone could provide other solutions